# Unexpected result from sort command of linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, bash-scripting

I have a file foo.txt with this content:

```
chr1    15
chr11   5
chr11   8
chr1    7
chr2    23
chr1    35
```

I tried to sort it first according to the first column, and then according to the second column for breaking ties by the following command in linux shell:

```
sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2n foo.txt
```

But the result is stange:

```
chr1    7
chr1    15
chr11   5
chr11   8
chr1    35
chr2    23
```

What I expected was this:

```
chr1    7
chr1    15
chr1    35
chr11   5
chr11   8
chr2    23
```

**EDIT**
I checked the characters in file with `od -fc foo.txt` as suggested in comments, there were no strange characters. Here is the result:

```
0000000   3.5274972e-09   8.7240555e-33   3.5274972e-09    8.716562e-33
          c   h   r   1  \t   1   5  \n   c   h   r   1   1  \t   5  \n
0000020   3.5274972e-09   8.8610065e-33   3.5274972e-09   2.5496164e+21
          c   h   r   1   1  \t   8  \n   c   h   r   1  \t   7  \n   c
0000040   2.1479764e-33   2.5493397e+21   2.1359394e-33     9.37439e-40
          h   r   2  \t   2   3  \n   c   h   r   1  \t   3   5  \n
0000057
```

I am using `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.21`

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, I get your expected output, GNU sort version 8.21

Comment: Are there any strange characters in the file? Try `od -c foo.txt`

Comment: Output is also as expected with Cygwin sort (GNU coreutils) 8.15

Comment: @glennjackman I have updated the question according to your comment

Comment: @DavidPostill The problem got worse! I guessed I am missing some input argument...

Comment: You may be using a different locale: what you you get: `env | grep -E '^(LANG|LC)'` -- try also `LC_COLLATE=C sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2n foo.txt`

Comment: @glennjackman LANG=en_US.UTF-8    LANGUAGE= (empty)

Comment: @glennjackman Oh! I once used LC_COLLATE=C as a separate command and then performed sort, it did not change the result. But using either LC_COLLATE=C or LC_ALL=C as a prefix to sort command worked like a Charm. Are you willing to describe this as an answer? I will be happy to mark it accepted then

Comment: @glennjackman I also have `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and `LANGUAGE` undefined but I get the correct output? Why is Ali getting the wrong output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your locale's sorting preferences where the issue. You can specify it in your environment, then any command that uses it (including `sort`) will obey it:

```
export LC_COLLATE=C
sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2n foo.txt
```

Or you can specify that value just for the duration of the sort itself

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2n foo.txt       # or
env LC_COLLATE=C sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2n foo.txt
```